# VirtualBox enables microphone input when booting VM on macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, virtualbox, vagrant

Since upgrading to macOS Mojave, VirtualBox seems to activate the microphone input when I boot a VM (via Vagrant).

This annoys me because when the microphone is activated, my headphones switch into some sort of "call mode".

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the audio for the VM solved it for me:

- Open VirtualBox (gui)
- Stop the VM
- Go to `Settings` for the VM
- Click on `Audio` tab
- Uncheck the `Enable Audio` checkbox and click `OK`
- Start the VM again.

Hope it also works on your machine :-)